# How To solve this java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DISMISS_AND_NOTIFY?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to execute the below code but i am getting this exception.The code seems to be ok and i have checked other things also but it is showing the same exception.

My code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;



public class Prog29 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver unitDriver= new HtmlUnitDriver(); 
        unitDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        unitDriver.get("http://google.com");

        System.out.println("title of the page is :"+unitDriver.getTitle());

        WebElement element = unitDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']"));
        element.sendKeys("Selenium");

        unitDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("title of the page is :"+unitDriver.getTitle());
        unitDriver.close();

    }

}
```

Exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DISMISS_AND_NOTIFY
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:225)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:191)
    at level1.Prog29.main(Prog29.java:16)
```

I am using:

1. firefox - 47.0.1
2. selenium driver - 2.53.1
3. htmlunit driver - 2.30.1

*If I update firefox then I cannot use firepath and firebug.*
*And if I update selenium driver then I have to update the firefox.*

Comment: Which line throws an error?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Stack trace indicates constructor of `HtmlUnitDriver` so that would be first line of `main`

Comment: Your code works fine. You will have to upgrade the selenium version to 3.13.0 and FF version also. Thanks !

Comment: if i update firefox and selenium then i cannot use firepath and firepbug ,.so any alternative?

Comment: How do you write the xpath or any locator ? Are you heavily dependent on Firepath or fireBug ? If you are dependent on those : then there are couple  more dev tools. generally I do not prefer Firepath. You can just google it about that.

Comment: i will try this code after updating selenium and firefox . can you tell me some similar tool like firepath .Thanks btw .

Comment: thank you @cruisepandey . code works fine after updating.

Comment: No problem. Glad it was little bit of help.